# serialization issue while using ApacheMQ for tridion object cache

Tags: 2013, cache, jms, object-cache

I am using SDL tridion object caching with ApacheMQ. I have deployed apachemq as a window service and it is running fine. During invalidation of messages I am getting the error below

```
2017-01-19 14:17:24,553 ERROR JMSCacheChannelConnector - JMS Exception occurred during reception of event. Attempting setting up JMS connectivity again
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class com.tridion.cache.CacheEvent! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes.
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.getObject(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:208) ~[activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector.handleJmsMessage(JMSCacheChannelConnector.java:213) ~[cd_cache.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector$2.onMessage(JMSCacheChannelConnector.java:84) [cd_cache.jar:na]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dispatch(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1401) [activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.dispatch(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:131) [activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.iterate(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:202) [activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133) [activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48) [activemq-client-5.14.3.jar:5.14.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_80]
```

As per apachemq documentation "http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html" I need to explicitly add the package to trusted list but i am not sure where I am suppose to add this entry in deployer.

Comment: Have you looked at article: http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html

Comment: Yes, I did and made the changes in mq side but i do not know what changes need to be made at deployer and CD side. I am not sure if there is any config which can be modified in deployer for mq settings or if we can do it in cd_storage

Comment: Versions 5.12.2 and 5.13.0, ActiveMQ enforces users to explicitly whitelist packages that can be exchanged using ObjectMessages. We moved to version 5.11 which and it started working.

Comment: @rdhaundiyal Sounds like you should answer your own question with that

Comment: But that is just a  workaround. My java knowledge is quite limited but I am sure, I am missing some config through which version 5.13 will also start working.

Comment: @rdhaundiyal  did u find any solution??i m also facing same issue.

Comment: No, but apache mq 5.11.1 is working fine for me so we downgraded to that version

Answer (score 3):

Apache ActiveMQ is blocking the JMS ObjectMessages for security reasons. This is the default configuration.

Configure ActiveMQ to allow ObjectMessages to be deserialized. Either enable it for all ObjectMessages or just for com.tridion.cache.CacheEvent.

Explanation and instructions are here: http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html.

If you're running ActiveMQ on Windows then you can configure this in wrapper.conf.

```
wrapper.java.additional.13=-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES="*"
```

**Note:**

The '13' in the above line may need changing, depending on your configuration. Look at the 'Java Additional Parameters' section in wrapper.conf.

Alternatively, To add this java argument `-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES="*"` in the micro services start up script.

Answer (score 0):

We got the same issue with DXA Model service 2.0.2 (in-process) - even after configuring ActiveMQ by updating wrapper.conf and reinstalling ActiveMQ.

Following error was found in :cd_clientlog file (for model service)

```
2019-07-03 16:19:40,413 ERROR c.t.c.JMSCacheChannelConnector - JMS Exception occurred during reception of event. Attempting setting up JMS connectivity again 
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class com.tridion.cache.CacheEvent! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes.
```

To resolve this issue, update InstallService.ps1 (of model service) and add java options as follows:

```
$jvmoptions = "-Xrs", "-Xms256m", "-Xmx512m", "-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=""*"""
```

Uninstall and install Model service, *JMSCacheChannelConnector* error should not be there anymore.

(You can use [prunmgr.exe](http://www.apache.org/dist/commons/daemon/binaries/) to update javaoptions of already installed service, and restart the service)